# What is the right way to set up a many to many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I've got three models in my app, a User, Review and a Movie model. A user can review many movies (one per movie), a Movie can have many reviews from many users. Their connection is a review.

Am I doing the following setup right?

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :through => :users

end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, :through => :movies

end
```

I'm hoping I can do something like:

`User.reviews` (which would give me back the user's reviews and the corresponding id of the movie which the review relates to)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the approach you should be taking

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :movies, :through => :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, :through => :reviews
end
```

You would also want to validate uniqueness in the model `Review` and/or enforce uniqueness on the join-table to only allow a single user per movie. It's up to you if you want to take this UQ constraint into the schema as well (DHH says 'Yes', I say 'the slathering of dumb persistance' is a 'No no'...)

`User.reviews` will give you the 'join records', i.e. along the lines of `<Review user_id=x, movie_id=y>`  Certainly, you'd have a lot more columns on the join table pertaining to the review, such as `:summary, :content` etc.  It's easy enough to access the movie from a review, i.e. `Movie.find_by_id(User.reviews.last.movie_id).title`

Comment: I always add a unique index in the DB as well, since the Rails validation does not guarantee uniqueness, especially on heavily trafficked apps. You can then rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique  and handle those rare occasions yourself.